# Как сделать на js скрипт, который будет обрабатывать клики как двойные?

Tags: javascript

Есть страница сайта, где нужно, чтобы клики по определенным элементам (элементы DIV или кнопки с определенными ID или class) обрабатывались как двойные. Пробовал разные варианты на JS с форумов, но так как с языком не очень хорошо знаком решить проблему не получилось.
Например, кусок кода:

```
<div class="form_radio_btn" id="1667726005820"> ... </div>
```

Нужно чтобы при клике внутри него все клики были двойными, а не одинарными. Такое возможно?

Comment: Будет проще что-либо подсказать, если поясните для чего это нужно. И приведите, пожалуйста, код, который пробовали

Comment: А какая разница, произошел клик или двойной клик? Какую задачу пытаетесь решить?